# Databinding and parent scope in angular not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I've been making progress on a problem I've been having but I'm not sure where to go from here.

In my code I have a module, and then a directive outside of the modules on its own, but it is injected.

I have an object called `registrants`, in the parent scope. When I kick in the directive, any activity in the directive modifies the parent scope and `registrants` will update. However, I have another variable `registrantCount` that should be updating as the registrant list length increases but it isn't. Can someone explain to me why?

Here is the snippet of my code that contains all the relevant peices below, if there is a variable that is shown that I didn't mention in the description above, assume the data is correct for it, for the sake of completion. The only variables I am concerned with are the two I mentioned in my initial problem statement.

**module**

```
angular.module('register', [])
.controller('Register', function($scope, $rootScope, $http){
    $scope.registrants = {};
    $scope.registrantCount = 0;

    $http({
        url : 'apiLink for initial data'
    }).then(function(data){
        $scope.employeeList = data.data.payload[0]; // initial list to allow the directive to function
    });
});
```

**directive**

```
angular.module('register.check', [])
.directive('attendees', function($http){
    return {
        restrict : 'EA',
        scope : false,
        templateUrl : 'template',
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs){
            angular.forEach(companies, function(c, key){
                if(c.companyID == id){
                   scope.registrants = c.registrants; // this object is modified in the directive template
                   scope.registrantCount = scope.registrants.length; // this variable is located in the parent template, not the directive template
                }
            });
        })
     };   
});
```

Again please note that the directive will modify the parent scope object of registrants but it will not modify the registrant count, nor will it generate a correct length in the parent variable if i modify it in the directive. I am very confused on this matter. Thank you for all the help ahead of time!

Comment: Can you post your HTML that implements the directive?

Comment: @mark-hill, unlike `registrants`, `registrantCount` is a literal binding (i.e. `number` type), so updates within your directive may not appear as expected. Try throwing the count inside another object and do the update through that for confirmation that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs?rq=1) for a more in-depth explanation of what's going on, but in short:

Binding in Angular can be kind of tricky. Because `$scope.registrants` is an object, the child scope (your directive) references it directly - it's pointing to the same object. Because `$scope.registrantsCount` is an integer (consider it a primitive type), your directive creates a separate variable for it and the two-way binding is broken.

Two options: Do as miqid suggested, and create an object containing registrantsCount:

```
$scope.registrantsCount = { count: 0 }
```

and update it in your directive thusly:

```
scope.registrantsCount.count = scope.registrants.length;
```

...or create a function in your controller and call it from your directive:

```
// in controller
$scope.registrantsCount = 0;
$scope.updateRegistrantsCount = function(count) {
    $scope.registrantsCount = count;
}
// in directive
scope.updateRegistrantsCount(c.registrants.length);
```

I prefer the latter.